# how to convert this (month/day/year ) date format to actual timestamp in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have date in this format **month/day/year**. How i can convert this date to actual timestamp. in ruby on rails.

e.g.

date = 6/21/2021

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: `date = 6/21/2021` – that’s not a valid object. Maybe you have a string?

Comment: `Date.strptime('6/21/2021', '%m/%d/%Y')`. See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and (for formatting directives) [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need format that string to valid format to convert to date, something like this:

```
old_format = '6/21/2021'.split('/')
old_format[0], old_format[1] = old_format[1], old_format[0]
old_format.join('/').to_date
```